# Fitting a sprocket on a small motor shaft

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machining, machine-design

I have a bit of a newbie question. I've inherited a mechanical system, wherein the motor has a D-type output shaft with a diameter of 8mm. 
(https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-High-Torque-Worm-Reducer-Geared-Motor-Electric-Motor-with-Reduction-Gearbox/312731356078?hash=item48d03dcbae:m:mLcgZdBy9RmkbntdUcP9aDA)

The motor is supposed to drive a component which has a sprocket (12.7 mm pitch, or 08b-1 standard, if you prefer.)

I've been trying to find a suitable sprocket, however it seems the smallest bore I could find was 10mm, in short - I need to fit a large sprocket on a small shaft. I've been looking at taper bushes, collars, etc.

Is there any way I can increase the diameter of the motor shaft, so that I can install the sprocket via a grub screw?

It is, perhaps, worth mentioning that I don't have access to a lot of tools, thus my machining capabilities are quite limited.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your best bet is to search harder for a sprocket with a 8mm bore. By the way, set screws are not a good way to afix gears and such to shafts (IMO).

Comment: I agree with Eric, thats your best shot.